# SQL Stored Procedure to Check if exists then add. If not to update

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to populate a user table (Named CSLL.Users)

The procedure is given a series of user details when triggered.

It then checks to see if the Alias exists in the table. If not it adds the alias. The sp then goes on to populate the rest of the columns (using the update command)

It is called using vba, but is throwing an error when it is called. I think it is with the first `IF NOT EXISTS` statement but can't see where I'd possibly going wrong.

```
ALTER procedure [CSLL].[UploadUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Name varchar(max) = NULL,
    @FirstName varchar(max) = NULL,
    @LastName varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Email varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Telephone varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Division varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Manager varchar(max) = NULL,
    @DirectReports varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Title varchar(max) = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] Where [Alias] = @Name) INSERT INTO [CSLL.Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) VALUES (@Name, 'UK', 'Employee')

UPDATE [CSLL].[Users]
    SET FirstName = @FirstName,
        LastName = @LastName,
        Email = @Email,
        Telephone = @Telephone,
        Division = @Division,
        Manager = @Manager,
        DirectReports = @DirectReports,
        Title = @Title
WHERE Alias = @Name

DECLARE @Pos int
DECLARE @DR varchar(max)

SET @DirectReports = @DirectReports + ','

WHILE LEN(@DirectReports) > 0
    BEGIN

    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @DirectReports, 1)

    SET @DR = (CASE @Pos
        WHEN 0 THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(@DirectReports))
        ELSE RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(@DirectReports, @Pos - 1)))
    END)

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] where [Alias] = @DR) INSERT INTO [CSLL].[Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) VALUES (@DR, 'UK', 'Employee')

    SET @DirectReports = RIGHT(@DirectReports, LEN(@DirectReports) - @Pos)
    END
```

Comment: Post the full error.Does it compile in sql server?

Comment: "It is throwing an error when called" -- *what* error?

Comment: It compiles in sql server and comes back with `Invalid object name CSLL.Users` error in vba

Comment: You've enclosed `[CSLL.Users]` as a single object name. You want `[CSLL].[Users]`. You also probably want `BEGIN` and `END` around your `IF`s.

Comment: Just seen it - I've got the brackets in the wrong place I've got `[CSLL.Users]` and should be `[CSLL].[Users]`

Comment: It's going to be  `INSERT INTO [CSLL.Users]`.

Comment: Have you tried using a `MERGE` statement?

Comment: Yes as TZHX pointed out. TZHX - if you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by a typo:

```
-- you currently use: [CSLL.Users]
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] WHERE [Alias] = @Name) 
    INSERT INTO [CSLL.Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) 
    VALUES (@Name, 'UK', 'Employee')
```

Instead try:

```
-- use: [CSLL].[Users]
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [CSLL].[Users] Where [Alias] = @Name) 
    INSERT INTO [CSLL].[Users] ([Alias], [Country], [Role]) 
    VALUES (@Name, 'UK', 'Employee')
```